# How to update every cell in a TableView [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, frontend

Is it possible to update every cell in a TableView with JavaFX? Actually, I get a new object in an ObservableList and, automatically, I also get a new row in the TableView.

But I also need to update the other rows. Is it possible? As far as I understand, the code below update just the first row in the table.

```
@Override
            public TableCell<AtisMessage, String> call(TableColumn<AtisMessage, String> param) {
                final TableCell<AtisMessage, String> cell = new TableCell<AtisMessage, String>() {
                    private TextFlow tf;

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            Text text = new Text(item.toString());
                            tf = new TextFlow(text);
                            tf.setPrefWidth(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                            tf.setMaxHeight(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                            setGraphic(tf);
                        }
                    }
                };
                cell.setPrefHeight(65); 
                return cell;
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't update anything by itself... Could you add a description of what you're trying to achieve to the question?

Comment: I have to change the value inside the rows for each new row added

Comment: Change how? Currently it's a bit hard to come up with a scenario where I'd do something like this instead of just modifying the table items. A better description of how the rows should be changed would certainly help. Currently this seems like an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In just one of the column, I have for every row different String, I have to change this string. That's all.

Comment: I still don't get how this is different to the standard approach. Using an appropriate item class let's you modify the values of the columns independently. E.g. in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2229/tableview/7288/sample-tableview-with-2-columns#t=201607251309562789202 you could also use a loop to go through every item and set a new `name` and/or `size`.

Comment: @fabian I try to explain it better. I have a simple TableView with two columns. This table is automatically updated if the ObservableList get a new Entry. This entry is an object with 2 properties (2 Strings: each for one column). The problem is: when I get a new entry, I have to change the strings in the other rows. The first row is automatically inserted (but I want to change the others too). All of them.